# Why is it i can't display image? i been trying so many different codes but the image still doesn't display

Tags: php, html

Why is it i can't display even update image and save it?

I have the following code:

```
<tr>
            <td>Email Address:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='textead' value="<?php echo $st_row['emailAddress'] ?>"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Profile Picture:</td>
            <td><img src="<?php echo $st_row['picture'] ?>" height="100" width="100"/></td>
        /* this is the problem it cant display image */


<td><input type="file" name="textpic" accept="image/*" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type='submit' name='btnsave' value='SAVE'></td>
            <td><input type='submit' name='back' value='CANCEL'></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: because *that* is not how IMG-tags work at all. please read [the manual](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/img)

Comment: the image i want to display is from my database can u help me how to display image from my database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMG tag should use this format :

```
<img src="<?php echo $st_row['picture'] ?>" alt="" />
```

But `$st_row['picture']` should represent a path to the picture after you handled the upload (which means using the PHP code to save the uploaded file on your server).

If this answer is insufficient, please provide more details (like the PHP code..).

Comment: thanks bro i can update picture now but still can't display i dunno why XD i tried so many codes but still can't display pic

Comment: Can you see the link in the generated code? Does it point to a live picture? Otherwise, you need to *handle the upload* with your PHP.

Comment: there's no link dude! only a broken pic

Comment: like this dude! https://elgg.org/mod/image_proxy/image.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsalzmancomputingsolutions.com%2FAvatarerror.png&token=6feb047ebfa90af712d66e0caabe8ff2f00b5ec1